# Eclipse neon.1 restart freezes while loading sql plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, fedora

I have eclipse neon.1 running on Fedora 24 64 bit. I left a SQL file open in my workspace along with a few other files and closed eclipse. Now whenever I try to open eclipse, the opening screen with eclipse logo freezes with the message - "Loading org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqleditor". To fix the problem, I tried restarting eclipse after deleting the RemoteSystemsTempFiles in my workspace directory - but the error persists. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running Windows?

Comment: Nope. Fedora 24 64 bit only.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1) Check the console for log with pathtoeclipse/eclipse -consolelog.

2) If you can't see anything wrong try pathtoeclipse/eclipse -clean -refresh.

3) Otherwise, Delete the .metadata folder in your local workspace. It seems that it contains a .LOCK file that if not properly closed, prevents eclipse from starting properly. On Unix based systems you can type following on command line:

```
rm -r workspace/.metadata
```